# Image Hosting Azure

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-cdn

I'm creating a website where users will be able to upload various images when creating a new page on my website. What service does Microsoft offer to host many user uploaded images. Would a Blob suffice? If so, if I were to add a CDN, would it be worthwhile? From what I understand, a CDN copies the images on various servers. If my local server has 1 million images, would that mean all the other locations will have 1 million images as well? Would that be very costly?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Blob storage is the perfect place for images in Azure.

CDN is great for when your images are at least somewhat static and will be viewed more than once.

With CDN you do not pay for storage costs (on the CDN), but instead for transfers out of the CDN - http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cdn/

I should also mention that if you're using Azure and Blob storage is your primary facility for storing images, Azure's CDN does not have to be your primary CDN - and any CDN will work.  CDN's are pretty commodity service these days.

HTH

Comment: Sure.  Please mark the response as Answered to let others know that it was helpful

Answer (score 3):

A CDN on top of Azure storage would be useful if you have lot of users fetching the same file(hot files/Cache hits) Accessing files that are not heavily  used will result in a Cache Miss. The CDN will then fetch the file from the origin (Azure Storage) before delivering it to the user. For such a scenario adding a CDN on top of Azure storage provides very little benefit.